# Where can I find wind speed and direction data for Pakistan?

Tags: data-request, weather, climate, asia, remote-sensing

I'm trying to link wind speed and direction to fire events from the NASA website.

Does anyone know where I can find such data?

Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

[Pakistan - Wind Measurement Data](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/pakistan-wind-measurement-data)

[Data repository](https://energydata.info/dataset/pakistan-wind-measurement-data) for measurements from 12 wind masts in Pakistan. Data transmits daily reports for wind speed, wind direction, air pressure, relative humidity and temperature. Please refer to the country project page for additional outputs and reports, including the installation reports: http://esmap.org/node/3058. For access to maps and GIS layers, please visit the Global Wind Atlas: https://globalwindatlas.info/ Please cite as: [Data/information/map obtained from the] “World Bank via ENERGYDATA.info, under a project funded by the Energy Sector Management Assistance Program (ESMAP).

[Pakistan Wind Resources](https://openei.org/doe-opendata/dataset/pakistan-wind-resources)

GIS data for Pakistan's wind resources in graphical files of seasonal and diurnal data from surface weather stations, graphical files of seasonal and diurnal data from Pakistan Meteorological Department (PMD), and Wind Power Density at 50-m AGL (above ground level) GIS data. The graphical data includes graphs illustrating hourly, monthly and annual trends in wind speed and power, prevailing direction, and frequency of speed, for over 50 locations throughout Pakistan.